# "Promisifying" a cached response

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have an async function that returns a promise. On the first completion of the function, I am caching the response. On subsequent invocations, if a cached response is available I wish to use this. How can I construct a promise to achieve this behavior?

Would something like this work?

```
if(this.cachedResult) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(this.cachedResult);
    }).then(success.bind(this));
}

return this.myService.getSomethingAsync()
        .then(success.bind(this))
        .fail(fail);
```

Comment: This is how I do it with jQuery's promises: http://jsfiddle.net/tk54x4ug/ Maybe it can help

Comment: just use a memoize function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it would kind of work.

It could be easily:

```
if(this.cachedResult) {
    return $q.when(this.cachedResult)
}
var that = this
return getFromService().then(function(res){
    that.cachedResult = res
    return res;
})
```

Instead of the constructor bit. Although this opens the door to race conditions (what if the request is made 5 times while you're waiting for the first result? Five requests would be made.

So it is better to cache *the promise* instead:

```
var cache = null
function myFunction(){
    return cache || (cache = getFromService())
}
```

Which is both shorter, more elegant and less prone to race conditions.

Comment: Ah, neat idea. In the instance that the cached promise is returned, when is the promise resolved? Or put another way, what triggers the resolution of the promise because I want it to be resolved anew each call, but using the cached data (if available).

Comment: @Ben: A promise is not "*resolved anew*" (it can only be resolved a single time), but it still allows you to add new handlers after it was resolved (and automatically calls them with the result then). The resolution is triggered by whatever the `getFromService()` in the original call did.